# Contextual Toolbar action mode is with background white on API 16/19

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm using API 22 as target and min API 16.
Using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity and a Toolbar.

On target (API 22) the contextual toolbar works normal, showing the actions buttons, etc. But testing on API 16 and API 19  the contextual action bar is getting the background as WHITE (maybe default) but not getting the correct background set as on API 22 does.

Any ideas what can be related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had found the solution for me.
The problem is related to styles and background of ActionMode.

Just added the two lines on my style:

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

It worked! My Toolbar in action mode get the background color now.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer ! You helped me. We need more people like you B-)

Comment: @Jack thanks for your comment and vote. I'm happy that it worked for you! Yes, let's keep spreading knowledge!